# Make bubble form to text while also having a max width

Tags: css

Hi I'm trying to make sections/bubbles where they are always the same size as the text within them even after the wrap.

The top bubble in this codepen should have no space to the right. IMessage does this on mobile but not in the desktop app.

https://codepen.io/ryanjso/pen/zYvrWZL

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello why does this text wrap like this</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Hello why does this</p>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;

  width: max-content;
  max-width: 210px;

}
```

Comment: it's wrapping because the container is hitting the max width you set... what are you expecting to happen

Comment: I think you're looking for `text-align:justify;`

Comment: @bryan60, I want it to wrap just as it is, however after it wraps I want the container width to then shrink to the width of the wrapped text

Comment: @ZohirSalak I'm not looking for the space between the words to change, but instead the width of the container

Comment: `max-width: 210px;` that is the width of the container, You can't have wrapping the container has enough space to fit all of it's content, a container will never shrink to fit when it's content has wrapped around, that's why i suggested  `text-align:justify;` to stretch the text to fill the empty space on the right not for space between words.